Kotlin Mutiplarform returns BuildConverter: AudioConverterNew returned -50 with AVAudioRecorder
I am trying to recording a mp4 audio using:
 session.requestRecordPermission { granted: Boolean ->
            if (granted) {
                val settings = mapOf<Any?, Any?>(
                    AVFormatIDKey to kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                    AVSampleRateKey to 44100.0,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey to 1,
                    AVEncoderBitRateKey to 32000
                )
                val url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
                memScoped{
                    try {
                        val error: ObjCObjectVar<NSError?> = alloc()
                        audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url, settings, error.ptr)
                        audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        println(e.toString())
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("Audio recording permission not granted")
            }
        }

but getting this error while running on a simulator:
     AudioQueueObject.cpp:1580  BuildConverter: AudioConverterNew returned -50
 from:  0 ch,  44100 Hz, .... (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 0 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
to:    1 ch,  44100 Hz, aac  (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1024 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame

I can see the file at the location but its not playable due to the conversion error.
I've trying a couple of different settings but keep hitting the same issue.
UPDATE
adding:
session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, null )
session.setActive(true, null)

clears the error but now I am getting:
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000332ba0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

UPDATE2 - Fix
By adding:
if(audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord() == true)
   audioRecorder?.record()

The .mp4 file is create successfully ;)
